# C # to VB.NET - Using interface

Tags: c#, vb.net, interface, class

Hey, I wonder how all this is in VB.NET

### In C#

```
UserSettings vUsers = new UserSettings();
UserSettings.IUserSettings vUserI = (UserSettings.IUserSettings)vUsers
```

---

I took a chance to try to write it in VB.NET, but is this right?

### In VB.NET

```
Dim vUsers As UserSettings = New UserSettings()
Dim vUserI As UserSettings.IUserSettings = (UserSettings.IUserSettings)vUsers
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be right, or you wouldn't ask, right? ;)

Comment: Thus, VS gives it no direct fault ... (UserSettings.IUserSettings) vUsers doubt I stretched on the written as in VB.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting directly in c#, so I should think DirectCast would be the method to use here.

```
Dim vUsers As New UserSettings()

Dim vUserI As UserSettings.IUserSettings = DirectCast(vUsers, UserSettings.IUserSettings)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a dikrete answers to my questions!

Answer (score 2):

it will be written in vb.Net as:

```
Dim vUsers As New UserSettings()
Dim vUserI As UserSettings.IUserSettings = DirectCast(vUsers, UserSettings.IUserSettings)
```

Further, you can try this for any C# to VB.Net conversion:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Where time we began to use ";" in VB.NET? : S

Comment: sorry, Updated my answer for that!!

Comment: Instead of `DirectCast` you might also stumble upon `CType(vUsers,UserSettings.IUserSettings)`. The two are similar, but don't do exactly the same thing. Most of the time you want to use DirectCast though (like in this case). For further explanation read http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/DirectcastVsCtype.aspx